# How do I use sample function for bootstrapping in R? Replacement row problem

Tags: r, sample, statistics-bootstrap

I am trying to create a bootstrap for the data frame 'ev_all_clean'

```
set.seed(1315)
boot_s <- as.data.frame(matrix(NA, ncol = 19, nrow = 1000))
for(k in 1:19){
  for(l in 1:1000){
  boot_s[l,k]<- sample(ev_all_clean[,k], size=1, replace=T)
  }
}
```

The above code returns

```
replacement element 1 has 768 rows to replace 1 rows
```

Help is much appreciated! Thank you in advance.

Comment: Can you share `ev_all_clean` df as well, so a proposed solution is tested?

Comment: Do you need to bootstrap all columns independently, or just bootstrap the dataframe by rows?

Comment: @saudic I need to bootstrap all columns independently

Comment: @deepseefan I could not share the data because it's proprietary but it has 768 entries, 20 total columns

Comment: Here's the list of the variables:

$gender
"numeric"

$area
 "factor"

$age
"numeric"

$wdays
"numeric"

$order
"numeric"

$whours
"numeric"

$ni
"factor"

$aware
"factor"

$max_v
"numeric"

$accel
"factor"

$max_r
"numeric"

$m_charge
"factor"

$t_charge
"numeric"

$p_charge
"numeric"

$f_mt
"numeric"

$p_mt
"numeric"

$p_buy
"numeric"

$interest
"factor"

$purchase
"factor"

Answer (score 0):

I just created a dummy `ev_all_clean` based on the spec you gave and see if this can get you started.

```r
boot_s <- as.data.frame(matrix(NA, ncol = 19, nrow = 1000))
for(k in 1:19){
  for(l in 1:1000){
    boot_s[[l,k]]<- sample(ev_all_clean[,k], size=1, replace=TRUE)
  }
}
```

Just a bit of explanation about what the script does:

`ev_all_clean[,k]` - loops through individual column and `sample` `1` element with replacement and that single element will be used replace the value at `boot_s[[l,k]]`. You can read about the difference between `[` and `[[` [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1169456/the-difference-between-bracket-and-double-bracket-for-accessing-the-el).

Since you're sampling a single element, you probably want to replace a single element and that is what the error message is trying to tell you -I think.

Comment: Thank you very much! The code ran but it ended up creating vector as a datapoint on the booted dataframe (So on the new dataset every cell becomes a vector based on the column with 768 datapoints inside each). I just want a number on every single cell of the booted dataframe.

Answer (score 0):

Once you have you original dataframe boot_s, to have your first bootstrap you could do

```
# first prepare a dataframe of the same shape as your original
samplemat=boot_s 
# then perform bootstrap for each column separately
for(k in 1:19){
  samplemat[,k] = boot_s[sample(1:nrow(boot_s),nrow(boot_s),T),k]
}
```

sample prepare a vector of the indices of the rows to keep in your bootstraped sample. 
You will have to do that for each bootstrap operation you want (you will want many).

Comment: Thank you! The code worked but I want to expand the number of datapoints (from the original of 768 to 3000 for example).

Comment: The number of rows is not hard-coded in my answer, you can put a dataframe with any number of rows. The number of colums is 19, but you can also treat that as a variable using `ncol(boot_s)` instead of 19.